# Calling symfony/process inside Laravel controller always returns "<command> is not recognized"

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I was trying to `git pull` by calling a spesific route.
I'm using symfony/process inside my controller like so:

```
public function pull()
{
    $process = new Process(["git","pull"]);
    $process->setWorkingDirectory(base_path());
    $process->run(function ($type, $buffer) {
        if (Process::ERR === $type) {
            echo 'ERR > '.$buffer;
        } else {
            echo 'OUT > '.$buffer;
        }
    });
}
```

when I hit the route it returns:

```
ERR > 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

then I tried to change the command to any other command like ls, npm install, rm, etc... and it is still returning the same error.

Comment: What is the underlaying OS your app is running on?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε my local dev runs on windows, but Im actually going to deploy it on linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To everyone who comes here;
In order to run the system commands such as from shell or cmd(either on windows or linux or mac):

```
$process = Process::fromShellCommandline('inkscape --version');

$process->run(function ($type, $buffer) {
    if (Process::ERR === $type) {
        echo 'ERR > ' . $buffer;
    } else {
        echo 'OUT > ' . $buffer;
    }
});
```

The output is:

> OUT > Inkscape 1.0.2 (e86c870879, 2021-01-15) ERR > Pango version: 1.48.0

Don't forget to read the documentation:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#installation